# Java: Further Defining Classes and/or Uses for Classes?

Tags: java, eclipse, class, libgdx, extends

I'm designing a game using the libgdx Java Framework and the Eclipse IDE.

I defined a character class. I want to use this class to define all possible characters as it contains properties that can be used for enemies, the player, and bosses.

However I can't figure out if I should extend the class or properly how to do so. Please if someone could get me started in the right direction it would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I have so far that I typed out in notepad (which Eclipse has not fully accepted):

```
package com.mygdx.game;

public class Character
{
//variable declaration
private int health;
private int dmg;
private String image;

//constructor methods
public Character(int setHealth, int setDamage, String setImg)
{
    health = setHealth;
    dmg = setDamage;
    image = setImg;
}

//movement methods
public void walkLeft()
{

}
public void walkRight()
{

}
public void jump()
{

}
public void hit(int damage)
{
    health -= damage;
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        //getWorld().removeObject(this);
        //this is code that was written while I was using Greenfoot but Greenfoot works differently than a regular IDE so I need to adapt this code
    }
}
public int attack()
{
    return dmg;
}
}
```

Below is an example of a class I want to create as a Character.

```
public class SilverGeneral extends Character
{
private boolean alliesDead;

public void attackArrow()
{
    dmg = 1
    Arrow a = new Arrow();
    getWorld().addObject(a, getX(), getY());
}

public void checkAllies()
{
    if (alliesDead == false);
    {

    }
    else
    {

    }
}

}
```

Comment: First, fix the syntax error with `if (alliesDead == false);` the semicolon completes the `if` so the `else` is unmatched. Also, `if (!alliesDead) {`  is shorter.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should use `Factory Design Pattern` in this case.

Have a look at this [example link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm) to get you started :

Comment: But with this I can't write my methods because my Character becomes an interface and I can't define methods. It makes it so I have to rewrite my methods anyways and honestly I don't see the benefit of an Interface in any situation.

It completely defeats the purpose of code reuse.

Comment: Java 8 introduced functional interfaces, so you can define your methods in interface.
http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2014/03/8-new-features-for-java-8.html

Comment: I have Java 8 but Eclipse says Interface methods are automatically Abstract and Abstract methods can't have method bodies.

Comment: That's strange. Did you try importing `java.util.function`

Comment: Also, take a look at template method pattern:
http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method

Comment: No just a sec let me try that.

EDIT: Worked. Let me try the rest of that first thing you showed.

Comment: Nevermind. It says only a type may be imported and that java.util.function resolves to a package.

Comment: Oh, I believe it should be `import java.util.function.*;`

Comment: That still leaves the abstract methods issue saying that they don't have a body

Comment: Well, check out this example, if it helps or look up more online: http://java.dzone.com/articles/introduction-functional-1

Also, check out template design pattern. Good luck!